# What is this calendar called?

Tags: single-word-requests, image-identification

It's a year-view calendar with days grouped into months and every month has seven columns corresponding to days of the week. I'm looking for an adjective. This is ______ calendar.

[image: calendar showing all the days in the year 2014]

Comment: A calendar is a *tabular array*(n.) of the days.

Answer (score 7):

I think you hit it with “year view”, though I would hyphenate it thus:

> This is a **year-view** calendar.

If you asked me “what's this?”, I would like James probably respond “it's a calendar”, but I would say the same if you showed me a month-view calendar. Since you specifically mentioned that it covers a whole year, it becomes a question of what terms do people use to distinguish **year calendar**s from month ones.

A larger year-view grid with spaces to write or draw in would be a **year planner** or may be mounted so as to be a **wall planner**. But your illustration isn't one of those.

Possibly the terms *(something)-view* have become more common because of their use in software applications like Outlook, where you may have a selector like:

> View: day / week / month

Comment: Huh. I never thought about that before, that there’s actually a difference between a planner and a calendar. Nice little “aha!” moment.

Answer (score 2):

I typed into Google: "*twelve months on one page calendar*" and found that expression is clearly used. One website calls it a [**yearly calendar**](http://donnayoung.org/calendars/calendars.htm), whereas a calendar divided into months is called a *monthly calendar*. There are also 13, 15, and 18 months calendars and a ***3 year calendar***. I just double checked and Google retrieves 494,000 results for ["yearly calendar"](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1KMZB_enGB547GB547&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22yearly%20calendar%22).

Answer (score 1):

I would just call it **a** calendar, but you could also call it "a single-page calendar."